# Exception Mapper maps exception but still throws

Tags: exception, jersey

I implemented an ExceptionMapper for ConstraintViolationException (bean validation). When I map an Exception that extends WebApplicationException everything works perfectly (the exception is not thrown anymore, just the response formatted with mapper is commited). But in the case of ConstraintViolationException, both situations occurs. Is there any way to don't throw Exception when mapping that?

[image]

Comment: Out of curiosity, what are you doing to generate a `ConstraintViolationException`?

Comment: I set up a form and send an invalid value to the bean to validate, which is annotated with @Valid and my custom validation annotation

Comment: This is pretty weird to me. Are you sure you aren't printing the stacktrace and then rethrowing the exception?